# dplyr: how can I write equivalent to table() base function and preserve column names?

Tags: r, left-join, calculated-columns, dplyr

dplyr is fast and I would like to use the %.% piping a lot.
I want to use a table function (count by frequency) and preserve column name and have output be data.frame.

How can I achieve the same as the code below using only dplyr functions (imagine huge data.table  (BIGiris) with 6M rows)

```
> out<-as.data.frame(table(iris$Species))
> names(out)[1]<-'Species'
> names(out)[2]<-'my_cnt1'
> out
```

output is this. Notice that I have to rename back column 1. Also, in dplyr mutate or other call - I would like to specify name for my new count column somehow.

```
     Species my_cnt1
1     setosa      50
2 versicolor      50
3  virginica      50
```

imagine joining to a table like this  (assume iris data.frame has 6M rows) and species is more like "species_ID"

```
> habitat<-data.frame(Species=c('setosa'),lives_in='sea')
```

final join and output (for joining, I need to preserve column names all the time)

```
> left_join(out,habitat)
Joining by: "Species"
     Species my_cnt1 lives_in
1     setosa      50      sea
2 versicolor      50     <NA>
3  virginica      50     <NA>
>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the first part you can use `dplyr` like this

```
library(dplyr)
out <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(my_cnt1 = n())
out

Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

     Species my_cnt1
1     setosa      50
2 versicolor      50
3  virginica      50
```

To continue in one chain do this:

```
out <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(my_cnt1 = n()) %>% left_join(habitat)
out

Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

     Species my_cnt1 lives_in
1     setosa      50      sea
2 versicolor      50       NA
3  virginica      50       NA
```

By the way, `dplyr` now uses `%>%` in place of `%.%`. It does the same thing and is part of the package `magrittr` as well.

Comment: tally() is great! Using tally() though, if you wanted a custom column name I suppose you would have to do this: `out <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% tally() %>% select(Species, my_cnt1 = n)`.

Answer (score 0):

`count()` may be a convenient option to get behavior similar to `table()`:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  count(name="my_cnt1")
```

For `table()`-like output with two factors:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  count(Petal.Width) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Petal.Width, values_from=n)
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can simply attach the dataframe and then run the table function. This will display the column names too.

```
> attach(iris)
> table(Species)
 Species
    setosa versicolor  virginica 
        50         50         50
```

Comment: OP said using just dplyr functions.